# Why onSharedPreference not called in second application?

Tags: android

I have read all the documentation on SharedPreferences, I have one app that has the global configurations, from which all apps will want to read at will and when changes occur. I can read the SharedPreference, but how do I register for its ChangeListener?

//App1

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("my.test.Config_preferences", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE)     
listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

     public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences arg0, String arg1) {
            Log.i("TAG", "!!! App1 OnPreferenceChanged()"); //WORKING!
        }
    };
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

//App2

```
otherAppsContext = createPackageContext("my.test.Config", 0);
sharedPreferences = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences("my.test.Config_preferences", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        String s = sharedPreferences.getString("Name", "0"); //OK value


        listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences arg0, String arg1) {
                Log.i("TAG", "@@@ App2 OnPreferenceChanged()");
                //NOT WORKING!
            }
        };
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good implementation.

First, as soon as the user uninstalls `my.test.Config_preferences`, all your apps lose their preferences.

Second, every application on the device can read these preferences -- not just yours -- which is bad for security and privacy.

Please give each application its own `SharedPreferences`. Or, if having one central set of preferences is necessary (e.g., app-and-plugins model), expose the preference data through something you can secure via permissions, such as a remote service using AIDL or a content provider.

Answer (score 0):

Final answer:

Replace

getSharedPreferences("my.test.Config_preferences", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE)

with

getSharedPreferences("my.test.Config_preferences", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)

Answer (score 0):

After I study the source code, 
I found base/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java
can answer your question.
notifyListener uses Memory to notify each other, 
so your two applications can communicate with each other.